# What is a "Usage Error: --settings |--slot-settings" in the azure function CLI when setting the config?

Tags: python, azure-functions, prefect

I was able to create a function app successfully through the cli but when I go to publish/create the function code, I get the error in the title.

I will say I'm following this documentation to create a blob trigger function with prefect so that's why I have the two more config settings in my code - https://discourse.prefect.io/t/how-to-create-azure-blob-storage-event-driven-prefect-2-flows-with-azure-functions/1479

```
az functionapp config appsettings set `
--name PrefectBlobTrigger `
--resource-group my_resource_group`
--settings "BlobConnectionString=my_blob_connection_str PREFECT_API_URL=my_prefect_api_url PREFECT_API_KEY=my_prefect_api_key "


Usage Error: --settings |--slot-settings
```

Is it an issue in the way i'm formatting the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're spot on, it looks like just a formatting issue. Can you remove any back quotes and make everything into a single line?

Comment: Yup that worked thank you! I was copy pasting that powershell script and I think it got errored in translation. Putting all in one line was the way.